# Unwanted nginx redirect to https

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have an nginx setup like this:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default-ssl.conf:

```
server {

  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name my.server.name;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.server.name/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.server.name/privkey.pem;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

#  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location /proxiedhost/ {
    rewrite ^/proxiedhost(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:6080/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_redirect    off;
  }
  <<<< A couple more of these blocks >>>>
}
  server {
  listen 80;
  server_name origin.ticktockhouse.co.uk;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/aptrepo.conf:

```
server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

        root /home/aptrepo/;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name aptrepo.server.name;
}
```

My problem is that when I browse to http://aptrepo.server.name, it automatically redirects to https://aptrepo.server.name, which I don't have a letsencrypt cert for. Of course, I could get one, but I don't particularly need it, and would like to get to the bottom of why this is happening.

I'm willing to believe it's the server block in the default-ssl.conf, but I'm confused as to why the other server block isn't something completely separate. I've looked around for an explanation, but unfortunately most articles/questions are around how to get https to redirect to http - obviously a problem I've already solved!

Comment: I do not see the https server section in your config for aptrepo.server.name. Does this the complete configuration of all servers? Do you use HSTS?

Comment: I would like aptrepo.server.name to be HTTP only, if that's possible

Comment: Of course it is possible. Do you use HSTS? Show a result of `curl -I http://aptrepo.server.name`. Where are you include `/etc/nginx/sites-available/aptrepo.conf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be the case of nginx not selecting the correct `server {}` block.

For testing purposes only, try commenting out `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` and see if this solves the problem on `aptrepo.server.name`

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and it does work. I also added the return 301 line back in, and it seems to work as I wanted originally. The reason I didn't want it as http was to cater for Debian machines that didn't have apt-transport-https installed.